# How can i convert .prc file to .mobi file

Tags: kindle, mobipocket

I want to convert .prc file of mobipocket creator to .mobile format.

Please suggest me any tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys found solution for this conversion

First download mobiperl from this [site](https://dev.mobileread.com/dist/tompe/mobiperl/)

After download mobi2mobi application from this [site](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=21763)

and follow the instruction given in site..

Hope this will help you in future :)